# Ввод/Вывод __float128 C++

Tags: c++, input, float

Подскажите как в C++ вводить __float128, потом вывести без знаков после точки

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вводить и выводить такие числа надо в виде строк.

Для перевод `__float128` из/в строку можно использовать функции [strtoflt128](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libquadmath/strtoflt128.html#strtoflt128) и [quadmath_snprintf](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libquadmath/quadmath_005fsnprintf.html#quadmath_005fsnprintf), соответственно. Но это при условии, что вы используете GCC и вам доступна библиотека [quadmath](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libquadmath/).

Пример:

```
#include <iostream>    
#include <quadmath.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int prec = 0;
    string format("%.0Qf");

    string in;

    cin >> in; // считывание числа в виде строки

    // перевод из строки в __float128
    __float128 r = strtoflt128(in.c_str(), NULL);

    r = sqrtq(r);  // выполнение некоторых операций с числом

    // подсчёт размера выходной строки, с учётом форматирования и точности 
    int n = quadmath_snprintf(NULL, 0, format.c_str(), prec, r);

    if (n > 0) {
        // выделение памяти под строку
        string out(n + 1, '\0');

        // перевод __float128 в строку, с учётом форматирования и точности
        quadmath_snprintf(&out[0], out.capacity(), format.c_str(), prec, r);

        // вывод результата в консоль
        cout << out << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Число знаков после запятой, которые будут напечатаны, задаётся переменной `prec` и числом перед точкой в строке форматирования вывода `%.0Qf`.

Чтобы проект собрался, не забудьте указать линковщику опцию `lquadmath`.